# Android Studio: Can’t change package name when creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio version: 1.3

When I start a new Android Studio project, I want to change the default package name like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Then, following the step, new project creation succeeded. However, the package name was never applied.

Comment: Have you tried to do right button on package, refactor/rename ?

Comment: your image not properly shown

Comment: you cannot upload images with your current StackOverflow reputation. Also, you have a blue underlined text on the right side of the text displaying the predefined package that says "Edit"

Comment: @Alejandro Lora  Yes ,i know how to rename the package.But my question is not rename after the project created.

Comment: @MariusBudin   I find the 'Edit' and edit the default packagename.Then i press 'Done' .But it is not effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known bug in Android Studio 1.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181740), and it is supposed to be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Thank you very much,I'm relieved

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Android Studio` and ti will fix your problem